# mySQL database using phpMYAdmin and Joomla3

Tags: mysql, joomla3.0

I have a database built in Php myAdmin, and I want to connect it to a form I have on a joomla3 website. But when I fill details in on form, all data goes to default joomla3 database and not my database. Anyone got any ideas around this ?

I need my front end form data connecting with my own database not the default database in Joomla.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post how you have everything configured.

Comment: Hi Jakob, that is my problem, trying to configure my database with my joomla site. I'm new to Joomla and phpmyadmin so any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want may be figured out by following [this Joomla docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Connecting_to_an_external_database) instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the great RS Forms component for a small fee - this allows complete control of the form and you can wire it to your own php script to process the form.
You need to be careful to protect your script from bad data designed to hack your site as people enter code into the form - js is not enough you need to scrub the data before you attempt to do anything with it.